# What I want to do is output a quote generator with changing text

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to generate some quote where the text and pic are random. Could someone please validate this code since it's not working.  When pressing Submit nothing happens.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>quote generator Javascript</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    quote = new Array()

    quote[0] = 'img/einstein.jpg';
    quote[1] = 'img/einstein.jpg';
    quote[2] = 'img/einstein.jpg';
    quote[3] = 'img/einstein.jpg';

    text = new Array()

    text[0] = 'hallo1';
    text[1] = 'hallo2';
    text[2] = 'hallo3';
    text[3] = 'hallo4';

    function popup(){
        if(['submit']){

            document.write('<a href="' + text[Math.floor(Math.random() * text.lenght)]; + '" ><img src="' + quote[Math.floor(Math.random() * quote.lenght)]; '" style="border:0px;" >');
        }
    }


    </script>

    <input type="button" value="random quote" id="submit" onclick="popup()">

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

your code doesn't work because of your `if` condition.
Since

```
(['submit'] == true)  // false
```

you never execute the `document.write` statement so just remove the `if`. Also

```
quote.lenght
```

should be instead

```
quote.length
```

(*idem* for `text`)

and finally, instead of document.write, use `innerHTML` method or `createElement/appendChild` methods to properly inject your markup

Comment: Do you mean something like this?

function popup(){
   document.getElementById('submit').innerHTML = '<a href="' + text[Math.floor(Math.random() * text.length)]; + '" ><img src="' + quote[Math.floor(Math.random() * quote.length)]; '" style="border:0px;" >';
   }
  }

Comment: you cannot use innerHTML method for a self-closing element like `input`

Answer (score 0):

Fabrizio's answer points out most of the issues with your code. I think you don't need the

```
if(['submit'])
```

line because the popup function will never execute unless the submit button has been pressed.

Also, when generating your random numbers, you need to do this:

```
text[Math.floor(Math.random() * (text.length-1))]
```

This is because text.length=4, but there is no text[4]